# Start SQLPLUS, which asks for password, executes a script, take arguments and exit without "exit" in the script

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, command-line, sqlplus

Assume this script *use_arg.sql*:

```
PROMPT Arg1=&1, Arg2=&2
```

From windows cmd, I can call it as

```
echo exit | sqlplus user/pw@db @use_arg a b
```

and the result is

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Tue Feb 16 12:10:07 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Arg1=a, Arg2=b
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

- I don't want to enter the password on the command line
- The script should not contain 'exit' as it may also be called interactive where the session should not end
- The script accepts one or more parameters.

I tried

```
echo exit | sqlplus user@db @use_arg a b
```

but Sqlplus will use "exit" as the password.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a 'heredoc' to generate a temporary script; from a batch file:

```
@(
echo connect user/pw@db
echo @use_arg a b
echo exit 
) | sqlplus.exe -s /nolog
```

I've included the -s flag to reduce the output:

```
C:\Users\some\path>use_arg.bat
Arg1=a, Arg2=b
```

Or if you want to supply the username and TNS alias but prompt for the password you can create a temporary script and run that:

```
@echo @use_arg a b > use_arg_exit.tmp
@echo exit >> use_arg_exit.tmp
@sqlplus.exe -s user@db @use_arg_exit.tmp
@del use_arg_exit.tmp
```

Which runs as:

```
C:\Users\some\path>use_arg.bat
Enter password:
Arg1=a, Arg2=b
```

You can put the temporary file somewhere other than the working directory, of course, and need to name it so it won't ever overwrite a real file you care about.

Comment: (Try it again with formatting)  
I don't understand your first solution, never heard of this syntax. However, when I entered it in the batch file I did not get a windows error- :)  
But I got errors from sqlplus (SP2-0306: Invalid option.)  
I used  
`(  
echo connect user@db  
echo @use_arg a b  
echo exit   
) | sqlplus.exe -s /nolog  `
  
(Without the password)  
  
The second solution should work. I'd prefer to not need a temporary script.

Comment: @Joe - the first version needs the password in there. I suppose that isn't really significantly different from your original command, now I look at that again. And trying to exclude the password gets the same problem you had too, with the wrong bit being taken as the password when it prompts. This would be simple in Unix but I don't know a way around it in Windows, other than having the batch file prompt for the password and then including it in the heredoc as a variable. Hopefully someone will come up with a better solution?